# proc tabulate format calculated column

Tags: sas

Here's my code. I know how to format the subtitle `Total`. But how to make the `Total` column be bold and red instead of default black?

```
proc tabulate data=HAVE missing;
class Date City/order=data preloadfmt;
format City $Areaformat.;
var Index;
table (Date=''), Index*(sum='') * (City='' all=Total);
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [keyword](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000620143.htm) statement.  That lets you apply a style (and other things) to keywords such as `all`, or even to statistics like `mean`.

To have the bold apply to the entire column, you can use `[style=<parent>]` to bring the style of `all` down, or you can apply it directly inline.

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class;
  class sex age;
  var height;
  keyword all/style={fontweight=bold};
  keyword mean;
  *Options - first brings the style from the all keyword, second applies directly.;
  tables (sex=''),height*(mean='') * (age='' all=Total)*[style=<parent>];
  tables (sex=''),height*(mean='') * (age='' all=Total*[style={fontweight=bold}]);

run;
```

Comment: This only apply to `Total` but not the figures under `Total` column.